# How to delete all debian squeeze logs?

Tags: linux, logging, log-files

What is the easiest way to clear all the /var/log/ logs so that it just looks like a fresh system?
I know that the fresh system also have logs, but I don't acctualy need the old ones....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to truncate logs:

```
cd /var/log
for i in *
do test -f $i -a -s $i && > $i
done
```

Comment: I can't do a 1 character edit, so I'll post it as a comment: the correct path is `/var/log` in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old now but I came up with a slightly more robust solution based on yarek's answer. First it will go through and delete all of the logs that were rotated out by logrotate (eg: dmesg.2.gz, auth.log.1, etc.) then it will recurse through /var/log/ for logfiles and clear them.

```
rm -rfv /var/log/{*.[0-9],*.[0-9].gz}
for i in `find /var/log/ -type f`; do
        if [ -f $i ] && [ -s $i ]; then
                echo "" > $i
        fi
done
```

I've found this very useful when prepping a live system for creating a live image.